# TypeError: string indices must be integers in json

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have a dictionary that contains a list like this

```
data = {'data': [0,0,4,279,14,46,10,5,
  0,0,1,257,13,44,10,5,
  1,1,254,0]}
```

When I am trying to convert this into json, it is giving me an error

```
json.dumps(data)['data']

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-94-ca909e16d3cc> in <module>
      6   0,0,1,257,13,44,10,5,
      7   1,1,254,0]}
----> 8 json.dumps(data)['data']

TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Comment: because `json.dumps` returns a `str`ing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are converting your dictionary to string if you want to convert your JSON String back to a dict you have to use `json.loads(json_string)` A JSON Object is in almost every Language a String representation of an actual Javascript Object You can use it as a dict in Python but if you want it to export it you need to make string of it

Comment: or just use the Python dictionary

Comment: Didn't get. What change should I make in the code?

Comment: @PeakyBlinder remove `["data"]` part